# Flutter app on iOS throws SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'google.com' (OS Error: nodename nor servname provided, or not known, errno = 8)

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, sockets, lookup

Flutter app on iOS when on mobile data throws the following error:

`SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'google.com' (OS Error: nodename nor servname provided, or not known, errno = 8)`

when running the following code:

```
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com',
          type: InternetAddressType.IPv4);
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        hasConnection = true;
      } else {
        hasConnection = false;
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      hasConnection = false;
    }
```

App on Android or iOS with WiFi works well. Tested on two real devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the parameter `type: InternetAddressType.IPv4`. This requires that the returned address is *only* of type IPv4, which may not be the case for devices that are connected to the internet using IPv6. Using the default parameter (`type: InternetAddressType.any`) solves the problem